# How to show momentum operator are plane waves using translation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction, plane-wave

Using the momentum operator $ \hat{p}\rightarrow-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx} $ and the translation operator $ e^{-i\hat{p}a/\hbar}\psi(x)=\psi(x-a) $, how to I go about showing that the eigenfunctions of the momentum operator are plane waves?  Do I assume $ \psi(x) $ is an arbitrary plane wave and see what happens when I apply $ e^{-i\hat{p}a/\hbar} $ or something else?  Not sure...

Comment: Just solve the equation $-i\hbar \partial_x \psi(x,y,z)= p\psi(x,yz)$.

Comment: The eigenfunctions of translations are obviously plane waves, and thus, likewise, the eigenfunctions of their logarithm.